# weird behavioure on how sharepoint manage the permission for the built-in "Style Library" inside a Team Site,

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, publishing-site, style-library

I am working on a SharePoint Server 2013 (on-premise) and I have added a site collection of Team Site, then I enabled the publishing site collection and site features.

Then I edited the permission of the built-in Members group and give them Contribute instead of Edit.

Now in this case Contributor users can add/edit/delete list items , but they can not edit list/libraries settings, which is what i am looking for.

But the above is valid for all the built-in lists such as "Site Assets", "Pages","Content and Structure", etc where Contributor user can add/edit/delete list items but they can not view/edit list setting... but the only exception i find is the "Style Library" where contributor users were able to access the Style library settings and change for example some versioning settings... but when they try to delete existing filse they got an errors that this site have not been shared with them..... so can anyone adivce what is going on inside the Style Library ?? how some a contributor user can chnage the Style Library settings, but he can not add/delete files inside the Style Library !!

Answer (score 3):

The style library is usually provisioned when publishing features are enabled and is provisioned with custom broken permissions from what the site root has.

It grants read access to all users via the Style Resource Readers group, then uses some of the built in groups like Approvers and Designers to grant other permissions. It is a more highly rigorous library than your typical Site Assets libraries.

Having said that, if you need to add other groups to be able to add or delete items, go ahead and do so. That is just how it works. If you want to figure out, go into the library settings, permissions, and do a Check Permissions on the user accounts in question to see what levels of access are affecting them.

Comment: Now when i access "Style Library" permission settings it shows that "This library has unique permissions." .. and for this it still grant Members Edit permissions .. but not sure why  those members are not able to edit existing items...   seems there is a lot of hidden behaviors of this library that i can not understand.. now in my case i am the site admin and i have wrote some custom css files, javascripts, upload our logo , and other images etc .. so i am not sure if these files should exists inside the style library?. now the idea is that i do not want users to

Comment: be able to edit/delete these files,, so is there any harm if i take a simpler approach and add a normal document library (named Resources) , break its permission and grant all user Read-Only permission and upload my custom css, java-script, logs and other files, so in this case i can guarantee that non-admin users will not be able to modify these files ??  or having these files inside the Style Library will provide some benefits for me? in other words will using Style Library provide benefits over just creating a new document library to store custom css, custom javascripts..

Comment: can you advice on my above comments please?